# How to type primed sum?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

I need to type a "primed sum" (a summation symbol with a ' at the top right corner of the summation symbol) in latex. How can I do this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The [amsmath package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) has documentation which suggests there are 2 choices, depending on whether your sum has limits or not.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[\sum\nolimits'\] %if no limits in the sum
\[ \sideset{}{'}\sum_{n<k,\;\text{$n$ odd}} nE_n \] %if limits in the sum
$\sum^{'}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Btw, how did you find this information?

Comment: You're welcome. The `amsmath` package is the gold standard for the "correct" look when typesetting math, so I checked their documentation (I have a local copy but I linked you to the user documentation). Page 3 says integrals and sums are on page 19. I went to that page and found the sum with a prime mark mentioned. I used their example to create a MWE (to catch any mistakes).

Answer (score 11):

I would suggest typesetting the summation (together with its limits) first, and then add the prime:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
  \sum_{i=1}^{10}{}^{'} f(x) 
  \mbox{\quad or \quad} 
  \sum_{i=1}^{10}{\vphantom{\sum}}' f(x)
\]
\end{document}​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

If the summation limits are too wide, this may cause the prime to shift away (further to the right). However, some use of `\mathclap` (from the [`mathtools` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools)) would be able to clear this problem. You didn't mention it, so I didn't include it here. Just know that it is possible.

Comment: This also works very well!

Comment: Yes, I love that there are people at StackExchange who can give multiple ways to solving the same problem. You can learn a lot reading answers to things you already know.

Answer (score 10):

The `amsmath` manual (p. 15) recommends using `sideset`:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\sideset{}{'}\sum_{\text{whatever}} x
```

(This works when there are limits to the sum, unlike, er, `\nolimits`.)

Comment: Works well! But not in situations like `\left( \sideset{}{^{*}}\sum_{whateverwhatever} \right)`...

Comment: Issues with brackets are addressed here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/412575

Answer (score 2):

If you are using in text formulas, this works:

```
$\sum^{'}$
```

otherwise, to have the best of both worlds (something under or over sum symbol *and* prime) in display mode you can write:

```
\begin{equation}
\sum^{\infty}_{i=1}\phantom{}^{'}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: When I type this, I get the ' on top of the summation symbol and not to the right of it...

Comment: Fixed, check now.

Answer (score 2):

Yes I agree with  Ant and to give more information you can read Mathmode.pdf, the very fine document of Herbert Voss. You can read this document with the command `texdoc mathmode.pdf`in a terminal

> About \sideset
>
> This is a command for a very special purpose, to combine over/under
>   limits with superscript/subscripts for the sum-symbol. For example: it
>   is not possible to place the prime for the equation 35.4 near to the
>   sum symbol, because it becomes an upper limit when writing without an
>   preceeding {}.Now it is possible to write the equation
>   \ref{eq:sideset} in a proper way with the command \verb|\sideset{}{'}|
>   before the sum symbol:

```
\begin{equation}
   \sideset{}{'}\sum_{n<k\atop n\ \textrm{odd}}nE_{n}
\end{equation}
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't seem any different from what is suggested in [Ant's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29694/5764).

Comment: @Werner yes but I wanted to cite the document of Herbert because we can find a lot of things about Math. and I added the description of sideset.

Answer (score 1):

Use `\nolimits` to force the prime to the right of the summation: `\sum\nolimits'`, to use it as a symbol of its own, you have to wrap it inside `\mathord{}`:

```
\def\xsum{\mathop{\sum\nolimits'}}
\[
\sum^{a+b}_{x+y=c}
\xsum^{a+b}_{x+y=c}
\]
```

Comment: That helps but create another problem. I still want to write something under the summation symbol (namely, the range over which the sum is taken). If I type "\nolimits", these things go to the bottow right corner of the summation symbol.

Can I have both things at the same time?

Comment: @averageman: see my updated answer.