# `\sideset` with parentheses

Tags: math-mode, spacing, amsmath

I am now trying to define some "decorated operators" similar to
[image: sharp sum]
in several ways and I want to find my preference on decorating operators.

A simple "prepared" way is to use the command `\sideset` of amsmath,
though the position of the limit-style subscript
may depend on one's preference.
Some month before, my friend told me a confliction of `\sideset`
with parenthesis, e.g. the code

```
\[
\left|\sideset{}{^{\smash{\sharp}}}\sum_{x<n\le x+y}\chi(n)a(n)\right|
\]
```

gives
[image: crashed side set]
so the limit-style subscript `x<n\le x+y` and the modulus sign `\left|`
clash each other.

I thought that this is because `\sideset` turns math operators
to ordinary math atoms. Therefore, I tried to use `\mathop` as follows:

```
\[
\left|\mathop{\sideset{}{^{\smash{\sharp}}}\sum}
_{x<n\le x+y}\chi(n)a(n)\right|
\quad
\left|\mathop{\sideset{}{^{\smash{\sharp}}}\sum
_{x<n\le x+y}}\chi(n)a(n)\right|
\]
```

this gives
[image: sideset with mathop]

I am still wondering why `\sideset` behaves not well with some parentheses
and why the above two applications of `\mathop` give so different results.
For me (as a beginner of LaTeX), the latter one of my `\mathop` applications seems more likely to avoid the clash, but the truth was opposite...

Thus, I would like to ask:

1. What is the reason of the above clash of `\sideset` and parentheses?
   Is my usage of `\sideset` wrong? Or is this a "bug" of `\sideset`?
2. If this is a bug of `\sideset`, what is a good way to avoid it?
3. Why my two applications of `\mathop` above give different results?

Note: According to egreg's answer, I found the above clash happens
since `\sideset` shift math operator "too much" if the limit-style subscript is too long. Now we let `\egregsideset` be
the corrected version of `\sideset` due to egreg. Then

```
\[
\fbox{$\displaystyle%
\sideset{}{^\text{quite very very very long}}\sum$%
}
\fbox{$\displaystyle%
\egregsideset{}{^\text{quite very very very long}}\sum$%
}
\]
```

gives

[image: comparison sideset]

which although I am not sure which one is better,
but I guess the original `\sideset` is more natural in this aspect.
Thus, I add a new question

4. How can we modify `\egregsideset` with avoiding the above difference with `\sideset`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is a bug of `\sideset`. If I try

```
\[
\left|\sideset{}{}\sum\right|\showlists
\]
```

I get

```
\mathinner
.\left"26A30C
.\mathord
..\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0
.\mathop
..\kern 0.0
..\mathord
...\hbox(10.50006+5.50006)x0.0
....\mathon
....\vbox(10.50006+5.50006)x0.0
....\mathoff
..\mathord
...\hbox(10.50006+5.50006)x14.44447
....\mathon
....\hbox(1.0+15.00012)x14.44447, shifted -9.50006
.....\OMX/cmex/m/n/10 X
....\mathoff
.\right"26A30C
```

so essentially **Open** **Ord** **Op** **Close**. This in contrast to `\left|\sum\right|` that shows

```
\mathinner
.\left"26A30C
.\mathop
..\fam3 P
.\right"26A30C
```

so **Open** **Op** **Close**. A visual comparison

[image]

shows quite a different problem than yours: the summation is too much on the right.

However, if I change the definition of `\sideset` to

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\sideset}[3]{%
  \@mathmeasure\z@\displaystyle{#3}%
  \global\setbox\@ne\vbox to\ht\z@{}\dp\@ne\dp\z@
  \setbox\tw@\box\@ne
  \@mathmeasure4\displaystyle{\copy\tw@#1}%
  \@mathmeasure6\displaystyle{#3\nolimits#2}%
  \dimen@-\wd6 \advance\dimen@\wd4 \advance\dimen@\wd\z@
  \mathop{\hbox to\dimen@{}}\!% <--- was only \hbox to\dimen@{}
  \mathop{\kern-\dimen@\box4\box6}%
}
\makeatother
```

so TeX will see a `\mathop` before doing any operation and the thin space between the two consecutive **Op** atoms is nullified by `\!`, I get the expected result:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\sideset}[3]{%
  \@mathmeasure\z@\displaystyle{#3}%
  \global\setbox\@ne\vbox to\ht\z@{}\dp\@ne\dp\z@
  \setbox\tw@\box\@ne
  \@mathmeasure4\displaystyle{\copy\tw@#1}%
  \@mathmeasure6\displaystyle{#3\nolimits#2}%
  \dimen@-\wd6 \advance\dimen@\wd4 \advance\dimen@\wd\z@
  \mathop{\hbox to\dimen@{}}\!%
  \mathop{\kern-\dimen@\box4\box6}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
\left|\sideset{}{}\sum\right|%\showlists
\\
\left|\sum\right|
\\
\left|\sideset{}{^{\smash{\sharp}}}\sum_{x<n\le x+y}\chi(n)a(n)\right|
\\
\left|\sum_{x<n\le x+y}\chi(n)a(n)\right|
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'm not really sure this can be fixed, because it might change existing documents.

However, the implementation of `\sideset` is buggy to begin with and you can test it with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\left|\sideset{}{^\text{quite very very very long}}\sum_{aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa}\right|
\]
\end{document}
```

(original `\sideset`).

[image]

I can offer a different implementation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\xsideset}{mmme{_^}}{%
  \mathop{%
    % half width of #3
    \settowidth{\dimen0}{$\m@th\displaystyle#3$}%
    \dimen0=.5\dimen0
    % half width of #3 with subscripts or superscripts,
    % half width of #3 removed
    \settowidth{\dimen2}{$%
      \m@th\displaystyle#3%
      \IfValueT{#4}{_{#4}}%
      \IfValueT{#5}{^{#5}}%
    $}%
    \dimen2=.5\dimen2
    \advance\dimen2 -\dimen0
    % prescripts
    \sbox6{\scriptspace\z@$\displaystyle{\vphantom{#3}}#1$}
    % postscripts
    \sbox8{\scriptspace\z@$\displaystyle{\vphantom{#3}}#2$}
    % typeset the thing
    \ifdim\wd6>\dimen2 \kern\dimexpr\wd6-\dimen2\relax\fi
    {%
     \mathop{\llap{\copy6}{\displaystyle#3}\rlap{\copy8}}\limits
     \IfValueT{#4}{_{#4}}%
     \IfValueT{#5}{^{#5}}%
    }%
    \ifdim\wd8>\dimen2 \kern\dimexpr\wd8-\dimen2\relax\fi
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
\left|\sum\right|\\
\left|\xsideset{}{}\sum\right|\\
\left|\xsideset{}{^{\smash{\sharp}}}\sum_{x<n\le x+y}\chi(n)a(n)\right|\\
\left|\xsideset{}{^\text{quite very very very long}}\sum\right|\\
\left|\xsideset{^{\text{quite very very very long}}}{}\sum_{\text{not quite so long}}\right|\\
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Crazy as usual :). I was *brave* enough to try to improve the question. If that's not ok then just let me know. I left the original image for now so that you see the change/contribution I made.

Comment: Thanks very much again, egreg! The answer went far beyond of my knowledge, so it took a time to reply. Your solution is very nice and educative, but if `\dimen@` take negative value at `\mathop{\hbox to\dimen@{}}\!` (which was the reason of the clash in my question), then some excess space will appear on the left side of `\sideset` since negative adjustment is cancelled by `\mathop`. Are there some trick to avoid this? (Conditional branches?)

Comment: > Dr. Mauel Kuehner, thanks for improvement, there is no problem to improve the question too!

Comment: @YutaSuzuki I'm not sure I understand the objection. Using `\hbox to\dimen@` inside `\mathop` doesn't change the typesetting except possibly for adding a thin space in front, which is the missing thing in the example and in general.

Comment: @egreg I explained what I wanted to ask in the edited question.

Comment: @YutaSuzuki Yes, I see. I guess there's something wrong in the logic of the computation. I'll try and work on it.

Comment: @YutaSuzuki It seems that the original `\sideset` has several other problems. I wrote a new implementation based on `xparse`.

Comment: @egreg Wow! Thanks! Finally I arrive at my (probably) most favorite way to decorate summations! (Note: This `\xsideset` did not work in xparse of TeXLive 2016, but work completely in TeXLive 2017.)